# Current Division

Tags: current

[image: The circuit]

The answers are :

i2 = 8.15
i3 = 3.06
i6 = 1.02 i8 = 2.04

I understand how to get i2

> For i3 :
>
> ```
> Combine R6, R7, R8 (Req1)
> ```
>
> (R6||R7) + R8
>
> ```
> COmbine R4 and R2 (Req2)
> ```
>
> R4|| R2
>
> ```
> Use current division
> ```
>
> Req of all = Req1 || Req2 || R3
>
> i3 = (Req of all/R3) * Is = I got 3.61
>   WHile the answer from textbook is 3.06

Is my method wrong?

I have wrong answers as well for i6 and i8.

Comment: R4 & R2 aren't parallel.

Comment: If that's the case the answer would be even higher

Comment: `R2` is in parallel with `(R6||R7 + R8)||R3 + R4`

Answer (score 1):

Since all resistors have the same value, let's call them \$R\$. Note that for \$I_2\$ we need to compute the current division between \$R_2=R\$ and the total resistance of the remaining network, which is

$$R+R||(R+R||R)=R+R||3R/2=R+3R/5=8R/5$$

So we get

$$I_2=I_s\frac{8R/5}{R+8R/5}=I_s\frac{8}{13}=8.15\text{mA}$$

The current through \$R_4\$ is then

$$I_4=I_s-I_2=I_s\frac{5}{13}$$

\$I_3\$ is then given by

$$I_3=I_4\frac{3R/2}{R+3R/2}=I_4\frac{3}{5}=I_s\frac{3}{13}=3.06\text{mA}$$

\$I_8\$ is

$$I_8=I_4-I_3=I_s\frac{2}{13}=2.04\text{mA}$$

And since \$I_8\$ is split into two equal currents (because \$R_6=R_7\$), you finally get

$$I_6=I_8/2=\frac{I_s}{13}=1.02\text{mA}$$